# Keydown/Keyboard events not working on dynamically created Link - React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

```
placeholder={placeholder}
            options={searchResults}
            onFocus={onFocus}
            onKeyDown={evt => onkeyPressed(evt)}
            renderMenu={(results, menuProps) => (
              <>
                {typeHead && !acrtInfo && (
                  <Menu {...menuProps}>
                    {results.map((result, index) => (
                      <MenuItem option={result} position={index}>
                        {result.order === 'C' ? (
                          <Link
                            id={result.terminalId}
                            to={`/home/trial/${result.Id}`}
                            key={result.Id}
                            autofocus="true"
                            onFocus={onFocus}
                            **onKeyDown={evt => onkeyPressed(evt, index)}**
                          >
                            <Highlighter search={menuProps.text}>
                              {result[label]}
                            </Highlighter>
                          </Link>
```

Hi Techies,
I need help on onKeyDown event. Since it's not working for me. I am iterating and forming links using Link in react.
I am attaching onKeyDown event to Link. But for some reason it's not working. The onKeyDown is not getting fired.
The Link is a child component as it's under menu and menuItem.
The one that is not working is marked in bold.

I have pasted the code above.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Nowhere in the documentation of [react-router , Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) mentioned that `Link` has a prop called `onKeyDown` ?! where do you get it? unless you mean `onKeyPress`

Comment: Did you want to use onClick instead of onKeyDown?

Comment: Thanks, I need to identify the key pressed, when the menuitem is choosen which is link.So, need that. If Link is not allowing keyboard events how to achieve the same.Even if the Link is changed as button , div the onKeyDown is not working.

Comment: Hi Grumd, I need both. I need to route when clicked and when enter key is pressed to the paticular item selected